# Typescript dynamic interface

Tags: typescript

I have a function I want to convert to generics Typescript to provide as an utility. I have reached it but what happens when a function returns a function. I know it is not required but still

```
/**
 * createConstants Type
 */
type createConstantsType =
  <T extends string, U extends string>(namespace: T, prefix: U | null) =>
    <V extends string>(...constants: V[]) => Record<V, string>;

/**
 * function for creating namespaced constants
 * @param {String} namespace the namespace for the constant to create
 * @param {String} prefix the prefix for the constant to create
 * @returns {Object} namespaced constants for a module/feature
 * 
 *    // Common approach
 *    export const NAMESPACE = 'manual';
 *    export const SIDEBAR_TOGGLE = `${NAMESPACE}/SIDEBAR_TOGGLE`;
 *    export const SIDEBAR_OPEN = `${NAMESPACE}/SIDEBAR_OPEN`;
 *    export const SIDEBAR_CLOSE = `${NAMESPACE}/SIDEBAR_CLOSE`;
 *
 *    // Usage of this utility
 *    export const NAMESPACE = 'manual';
 *    export const SIDEBAR = createConstants(NAMESPACE, 'sidebar')('TOGGLE', 'OPEN', 'CLOSE');
 *
 *    // which will generate:
 *    SIDEBAR = {
 *      TOGGLE: 'manual/SIDEBAR_TOGGLE',
 *      OPEN: 'manual/SIDEBAR_OPEN',
 *      CLOSE: 'manual/SIDEBAR_CLOSE',
 *    }
 * 
 */
export const createConstants: createConstantsType =
  <T extends string, U extends string>(namespace: T, prefix: U | null = null) =>
    <V extends string>(...constants: V[]): Record<V, string> => (
    constants.reduce((result: Record<V, string>, constant: string): Record<V, string>  => ({
      [constant.toUpperCase()]:
        `${namespace}/${(prefix) ? `${prefix.toUpperCase()}_` : ''}${constant.toUpperCase()}`,
      ...result,
    }), {} as Record<V, string>)
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to be aware of:

- Don't use `String` when what you mean is `string`. The uppercase one is a reference to the global `String` object in JavaScript.
- Avoid defining functions as `Function`. The definition of `Function` is very broad, and even if your function makes use of some precise types and generics, TypeScript will ignore all of that because it's told to treat it as just any `Function`. If you want to create a function type, write its signature this way: `type MyFunction = (argument: number) => boolean` instead.
- As a rule of thumb, if your argument is of type `string`, you can start just by creating a type parameter (a *generic*) and saying it `extends string`. So, `<T extends string>(argument: T)` instead of `(argument: string)`.

When you apply these rules, your solution will look like this:

```
export const createConstants = <T extends string, U extends string>(namespace: T, prefix: U | null = null) => <V extends string>(...constants: V[]): Record<V, string> => (
  constants.reduce((result, constant) => ({
    [constant.toUpperCase()]: 
      `${namespace}/${(prefix) ? `${prefix.toUpperCase()}_` : ''}${constant.toUpperCase()}`,
    ...result,
  }), {} as Record<V, string>)
);

const test = createConstants('manual', 'SIDEBAR')('TOGGLE', 'OPEN', 'CLOSE')
```

See [TypeScript Playground](https://links.wtf/OhMd).

Comment: This error means you are running an old TypeScript version. Try [TypeScript Playground](https://links.wtf/OhMd). It works as expected there.

Comment: i checked npm list typescript i m using 3.2.2. makes no sense. But thanks let me figure it out